# How do I apply filters and functions to previous rows in pandas?

Tags: python, csv, pandas, import-from-csv

I have a csv file with the following headers:

-Year

-Name

-Surname

-Gender

-Years_of_education

-Salary

-Days_of_vacation

For each row I want to take all the previous rows. Then filter with Gender or Years_of_education and find the average of the Salary. This will create a new column.

Using loops would look something like this:

```
import csv
import numpy as np

with open('data.csv', 'rb') as f:
    rows = csvfile.reader(f)
    for index, each_row in enumerate(rows):
        year, name, surname, gender, years_of_education, salary, days_of_vacation = each_row
        avg_salary = np.average([x[-2] for index2, x in enumerate(rows) if index2 < index and x[3] == gender])
```

My code with pandas so far:

```
import pandas as pd

filepath = '....'
header_names = ['Year', 'Name', 'Surname', 'Gender', 'Years_of_education', 'Salary', 'Days_of_vacation']
df = pd.read_csv(filepath, sep=',', na_values=['', '-'], parse_dates=True, header=None, names=header_names)
```

The proper use of apply is a bit unclear to me.

Comment: It would help if you could simplify and narrow the focus of this question.  But for starters, take a look at the documentation on shift().

Comment: Can you please ammend the question with a snapshot of your table and an example of exactly how you'd like your output to look like?